# Why can't I assign a function to Object.prototype.click?

Tags: javascript

I know how to create dynamic elements and append them to existing ones, and how to create click events and attach them. See my snippet below

```js
var container = document.getElementById("container");

var btn1 = document.createElement("button");
var btn2 = document.createElement("button");

btn1.innerHTML = "button 1";
btn2.innerHTML = "button 2";

btn1.onclick = function(){ console.log('button 1 clicked'); };   // this works fine
btn2.onclick = function(){ console.log('button 2 clicked'); };   

container.append(btn1);
container.append(btn2);
```

```html
<div id="container"></div>
```

I am trying to mimic jQuery's `.click()` behavior. (I don't want to use jQuery, I just need a shorter way of assigning click events to dynamically created elements).

What I mean, is I would like to extend `Object.prototype` by adding a function that accepts a function as the parameter, and all it does behind the scenes is assign it to the object's `.onclick` property.

However, the code runs, but no click event is triggered, and no error is reported.

```js
var container = document.getElementById("container");

var btn1 = document.createElement("button");
var btn2 = document.createElement("button");

btn1.click(function(){ console.log('button 1 clicked'); });  // this doesn't work
btn2.click(function(){ console.log('button 2 clicked'); });  // this doesn't work

btn1.innerHTML = "button 1";
btn2.innerHTML = "button 2";

container.append(btn1);
container.append(btn2);

Object.prototype.click = function(fn) {
   console.log('this function never gets executed');
   this.onclick = fn;
}
```

```html
<div id="container"></div>
```

I can tell that my extension of `Object.prototype.click` has not been executed since the `console.log()` never happens.

Is it because `Object.prototype.click` is reserved? If so, why am I not being able to override its definition?

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement

Comment: Also this may help: https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/from-jquery-to-javascript-a-reference--net-23703

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are two issues. First, you should assign to the prototype *before* you try calling `btn1.click()`, else the *native* `.click()` will be called. (The native `.click()` method of an element programatically triggers a click event on that element.)

The other problem is that `btn1` is an *element*, not just an object, and `HTMLElement`s have a `click` property on their prototype. So, even if you assign to `Object.prototype.click`, `HTMLElement.prototype.click` will be seen sooner in the prototype chain, and so your `Object.prototype.click` will be ignored. You'll have to either overwrite `HTMLElement.prototype.click` or `HTMLButtonElement.click`:

```js
var container = document.getElementById("container");

var btn1 = document.createElement("button");
var btn2 = document.createElement("button");

HTMLElement.prototype.click = function(fn) {
   console.log('setting up click event');
   this.onclick = fn;
}

btn1.click(function(){ console.log('button 1 clicked'); });
btn2.click(function(){ console.log('button 2 clicked'); });

btn1.innerHTML = "button 1";
btn2.innerHTML = "button 2";

container.append(btn1);
container.append(btn2);
```

```html
<div id="container"></div>
```

But mutating the built-in objects like this isn't very good practice and can lead to things breaking (such as if a library assumes that `.click()` will trigger the normal `HTMLElement.prototype.click` function) - you might consider assigning `click` property *directly to the instance*, rather than to the prototype:

```js
var container = document.getElementById("container");

function myCreateElement(type) {
  const elm = document.createElement(type);
  elm.click = function(fn) {
    console.log('setting up click event');
    this.onclick = fn;
  }
  return elm;
}

var btn1 = myCreateElement("button");
var btn2 = myCreateElement("button");

btn1.click(function(){ console.log('button 1 clicked'); });
btn2.click(function(){ console.log('button 2 clicked'); });

btn1.innerHTML = "button 1";
btn2.innerHTML = "button 2";

container.append(btn1);
container.append(btn2);
```

```html
<div id="container"></div>
```

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted to know. Thanks